# How to send Amount or decimal number to Visa Reader NFC in .NET app?

Tags: c#, .net, payment, card

Am search everywhere. I download SDK at this link https://github.com/developermypos/myPOS-SDK-dotNET
and actually many tries nothing works.

The visa reader of type https://geidea.net
I think it use COM Port..

I download the library at link above. all i need is simple Send for example a number 500 for example to Visa Reader NFC

Please tip me how you guys do it? how to achieve this? What is SDK used here? or How to send a number to COM port or something. maybe someone know.

[Visa Reader Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJiws.png)

Comment: It is connect by USB cable and is using a Smart Card interface.  So it would be similar to reading a disk in a camera.  The smart card is initially locked and you have to unlock before using.  You can use a window file explorer to view the card.

Comment: Noo its COM port i see it its like Lan Port or COM